# Spring @JsonFormat changing the timezone

Tags: java, spring, datetime, lombok

I'm sending JSON to a spring app, de-serializing it using @JsonFormat annotations and then returning it to the user. However my input specifically denotes "GMT" but the return data is "UTC". Is there a better/different way to annotate this properly so the timezone comes through?

**Request Body**

```
"startDate": "Sun, 22 May 2022 04:00:00 GMT"
```

**Object Annotation**

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z")
private ZonedDateTime startDate;
```

**Return Data**

```
"startDate": "Sun, 22 May 2022 04:00:00 UTC",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added `timezone` to the annotation

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", timezone="GMT")
private ZonedDateTime startDate;
```